# I receive the following error when installing angular cli

Tags: npm, path, angular-cli, node-modules

I am having problems with angular cli again (on a mac). Here is my log. I tried uninstalling the installing however get exactly same error. Any suggestions? Most probably PATH issue??

```
  0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'build', 'dev' ]
    2 info using npm@3.10.10
    3 info using node@v6.10.3
    4 info build /Users/user/Documents/Sites/website/dev
    5 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/user/Documents/Sites/website/dev/package.json'
    5 verbose stack     at Error (native)
    6 verbose cwd /Users/user/Documents/Sites/website
    7 error Darwin 16.5.0
    8 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "build" "dev"
    9 error node v6.10.3
    10 error npm  v3.10.10
    11 error path /Users/user/Documents/Sites/website/dev/package.json
    12 error code ENOENT
    13 error errno -2
    14 error syscall open
    15 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/user/Documents/Sites/website/dev/package.json'
    16 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/user/Documents/Sites/website/dev/package.json'
    16 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
    16 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    17 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check if you did npm --init because this might happen that you forgot to initialise npm and there is no package.json file present there which could not be found according to the line 5 of the error.

If that does not work then try this **npm install npm@latest -g**

If that also does not work then try these :

```
1. Ensure dependencies described correctly on package.json
2. Then type npm install and Enter.
3. Check issue still exists. and If issue not resolved, continue these 
   methods.
4. type npm cache clean and hit Enter
5. type sudo npm install -g npm and hit Enter.
6. Retry npm install and hit Enter.
```

Comment: Thanks fixed it, now Im having problems installing angular/material, a day gone already, sheesh!

Comment: According to stack overflow policy you should upvote answer or click the check box as the answer for your question instead of commenting thanks, BTW welcome ;P and what problem are your facing while installing angular/material?